# Jquery clone(true, true) not triggering event listeners in this case bootstrap's data-widget = "remove"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a default li that I want to make a copy of and modify every-time an event is triggered and append to a ul. If I remove jquery clone, it works fine with the event listener but when I add clone(), clone(true) or clone(true, true) it doesn't work.

I can't seem to figure what I am doing wrongly here.

This is my code below:

```
<li class ="default-list box box-warning box-solid">
    <div class="box-header with-border  draggable">
        <h3 class="box-title">Collapsable</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
    </div>
</li>
```

js:

```
$(".create-new-graph").on('click', function () {
    type = $(".tab-content div.active").attr('name');
    activeTab = $(".tab-content div.active ul");
    childrenLen = activeTab.children().length + 1;
    defaultList = $(".default-list").clone();
    defaultList.removeClass("default-list");
    defaultList.find("div.box-body").attr("id", type + childrenLen);
    activeTab.append(defaultList);
    time = ['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'];
    var data = [];
    y = 0;
    while(y < 24){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        data.push(rand);
        y++;
    }
    createGraph(data, time, 'tempabc', type + childrenLen);
    defaultList.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize all(or only the new) tooltips after the appending it back

```
activeTab.append(defaultList);
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by reinitialising the data-widget="remove". It is not clear to me why this has to done even after using clone(true) but this was what worked for me. Thanks for the heads up.